# Is there a relation between the area below and above the centroid?

Tags: geometry

If I were to draw a horizontal line through the centroid of a 2-dimensional shape, is there any relationship between the areas (or any other properties) of the two shapes formed? This should apply for non-symmetrical shapes as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your shape $S$ be the union of the two rectangles
$$R_1:=[-1,1]\times[-2,0], \quad R_2:=[-r,r]\times\left[0,{2\over\sqrt{r}}\right]\ ,$$
where $0<r<1$. The centroid of $S$ is the origin $O$, and a horizontal line through $O$ cuts $S$ up into $R_1$ and $R_2$. Now
$|R_1|=4$ and $|R_2|=4\sqrt{r}$, which implies that the area of $R_2$ can be made arbitrarily small compared to the area of $R_1$.